# How to depricated Fix import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, capacitor, fingerprint, face-id

Does anyone know what is the fix for the decricated import of ionic Plugins?

I'm following a tutorial and I cant proceed until I fix it..
i used plugin

> npm install capacitor-face-id
> [Enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-face-id)

```
import { Plugins, PluginResultError } from '@capacitor/core';
const { FaceId } = Plugins;
```

Many thanks

Comment: Try this plugin: https://npm.io/package/@willsub-npm/capacitor-face-id

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Capacitor 3.
This plugin seems to be compatible only with Capacitor 2 (see issue [#181](https://github.com/danielsogl/capacitor-face-id/issues/181)).
In Capacitor 2 this import type is used.